# How to fire some controller subroutine before_render in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I can hook [`before_render`](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious#before_render) and do next:

```
sub before_render_handler {
    my $c =  shift;

    my $extra =  $c->can( 'some_sub' );
    $extra->( $c )   if $extra;
    return;
}
```

But when template without action is rendered the `$c` is `Mojolicious::Controller` and not the target controller.
For example if we have `user/show` and have `App::Conroller::User` without `show` subroutine.

Despite on [DOC](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious#before_render)

> Passed the current controller object and the render arguments

We get here default controller and not current.

How to call `App::Controller::User::some_sub` when we are rendering template `user/show` for controller without `show` action?

**
As workaround, we can create bare actions for each such templates, but this  seems too ugly.

**UPD**
Even if action exists, but do not have explicit `$c->render` the rendering is in context of default controller

Answer (score 0):

I use a catch-all sub "view" in each controller, just route those non-action url to there.

```
my $r = $self->routes
#
# You have to match other routes before come to non-action route.
#
$r->route('/#controller')->to(action => 'view');
```